# rhythmbox tray icon

Tags: rhythmbox, system-tray

I don't know why, but Rhythmbox does not show up in tray.
I have installed and activated an additional plugin from [this site](http://mendhak.github.com/rhythmbox-tray-icon/) AND added 'all' to whitelist (dconf-editor -> com -> canonical -> desktop -> panel), rebooted the computer, but there's still nothing.

Comment: which desktop environment are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of ubuntu and rythmbox are you using? Other question could be: are you on gnome, gnome3 or unity?
Since Unity came, I'm not sure when, but the icon of Rhythmbox are hidden now in the sound option menu.

[image]

Here a snapshot.

Anyway, can you be more specific?

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer, somehow I didn't think rhythmbox controls would be in the sound menu... Thanks again! Regards.

Comment: This looks the same in Gnome 3 Classic. Clicking on the Rythmbox item does not open Rythmbox however.

Answer (score 6):

Starting with Ubuntu 18, the Rhythmbox controls are not under the sound option icon any more, but under the clock icon.

Comment: Your answer is great. Just want to add (for other readers) that this GUI change probably came with switching from the Unity desktop to the Gnome desktop.